# Phpunit: Testing files outside the testsuite

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm having a problem when running phpunit on my tests directory.
The default class inheritence is like this: `ControllerTest` > `ProjectTestCase` > `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase`.

Both the `ProjectTestCare` as the `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase` are located outside the tests directory.

This is what the `phpunit.xml` looks like:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="true" stopOnFailure="true">
<testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
    <directory suffix="ControllerTest.php">./application/controllers</directory>
</testsuite>
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>../../library/Zend</directory>
        <directory>../../library/Doctrine</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

The problem is that it finds `ProjectTestCase` and aborts because it contains no errors.

It doesn't match the testsuite directory **and** it doesn't match the suffix pattern.

Anyone who has encountered this problem or has a fresh idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have excluded directories I did not want to process.

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="ICAP User Interface">
        <directory suffix=".test">app</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="User Interface Library">
        <directory suffix=".test">lib/.</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".class">lib/UTIL</directory>
        <directory suffix=".fn">lib/UTIL</directory>

        <exclude>
            <file>lib/UTIL/AJAX.class</file>
            <file>lib/UTIL/CreateNotificationTypeFilter.fn</file>
            <file>lib/UTIL/NotificationView.fn</file>

            <directory>ExternalLibraries</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Comment: The `<filter>` is only used for excluding from code coverage, not from running tests.